# "The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context" exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, nancy

I'm rendering `Spark` templates in a console application and I'm trying to use `RenderPartial` like so:

```
${Html.RenderPartial("_mypartial.spark", myData)}
```

but I'm getting this error when compiling the view:

```
The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context
```

In the `Shared\_global.spark` I have added this imports:

```
<use namespace="System" />
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
<use namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
<use namespace="System.Linq" />
```

Everything else renders fine otherwise, it's just that `Html` is not defined.

It it makes any difference, I'm rendering this with an embedded `NancyFX` engine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nancy - how do you add htmlHelpers into the Spark virew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782458/nancy-how-do-you-add-htmlhelpers-into-the-spark-virew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem isn't within the view itself.  I'm not familiar NancyFX engine, but all engines views should be using a base view.  The default is in the web.config in the views folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
```

Of course you're not using razor, this is simply a comparison where `Html` exists on `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.  How you configure NancyFX, the configuration needs to define the one that supports the `HtmlHelpers` (that either come with MVC or NancyFX, I'm not sure).

After taking a [look at Gibhub](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor/web.config.transform) It looks very similar:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase">
```

And the [`NancyRazorViewBase` has `HtmlHelpers` on it](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor/NancyRazorViewBase.cs) so it sounds very much like a configuration issue.

Comment: Looks like the [Spark view base](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/9d3c650575cba109e620ab163f4fda26a0536036/src/Nancy.ViewEngines.Spark/NancySparkView.cs) doesn't have any helpers defined

Comment: Pretty sure I answered this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782458/nancy-how-do-you-add-htmlhelpers-into-the-spark-virew/11868166