# Rendering HTML content with @Html.Raw in Razor Mail Template

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using Razor page as Mail Template I am trying to display the content of the mail (Html Content) using `@Html.Raw(Model.Content)`.

Anytime I run the code I get this error: `html does not exist in current context`.

I tried this `@Html.Raw("<strong>Bold!</strong>")` on another razor page to validate `RazorEngine` is installed and it displayed perfectly well with no error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context" exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354588/the-name-html-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-exception)

Comment: @AaronHudon Did you read before you mark it as duplicate? What I am doing is different. It might be the same error but their solution won't work for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When doing e-mails, I use the RazorEngineService in RazorEngine.Templating, e.g. in my case, it looks like this:

```
using RazorEngine.Templating;

RazorEngineService.Create().RunCompile(html, ...)
```

Assuming you are using the same assembly, @Html.Raw does **NOT** exist with this usage.  I was finally able to get raw HTML output by doing this in my e-mails:

```
@using RazorEngine.Text

@(new RawString(Model.Variable))
```

Comment: At what point do I use `RazorEngineService.Create().RunCompile(...) ` ?

Comment: @uikrosoft, Sorry for the confusion.  If you're not using RazorEngine.Templating, then you would NOT see this.  You didn't post what code you are using to turn a .cshtml file into an e-mail.  That's why I'm just letting you see what I do and giving one possibility.  You can try adding `@using RazorEngine.Text` to your e-mail CSHTML page and then wrapping your HTML in `@(new RawString(Model.Variable))` and see if it works.  If you have the same assemblies loaded, that should work.

Comment: Life saver. I would have never figured out the "using". Without that, it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
@using RazorEngine.Text

@(new RawString(Model.Variable))
```

Use this code in Mail template cshtml view.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

My answer, uses hannes neukermans answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561164/razorengine-issues-with-html/54319658#54319658).

I needed to use RazorEngine in an MVC project to send emails incorporating html strings stored in a database so that they could be edited by admin users.

The standard RazorEngine config didn't allow @Html.Raw to work.

In my emails class I set up a new Engine.Razor (Engine is static) that incorporates the classes Hannes recommends. I only needed the Raw method, but you can obviously add others :

you will need these:

```
 using RazorEngine;
 using RazorEngine.Templating; // For extension methods.
 using RazorEngine.Text;
 using RazorEngine.Configuration;
```

These are the classes to provide the @Html helpers

```
public class HtmlSupportTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
{
    public HtmlSupportTemplateBase()
    {
        Html = new MyHtmlHelper();
    }
    public MyHtmlHelper Html { get; set; }
}  

 public class MyHtmlHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Instructs razor to render a string without applying html encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlString"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEncodedString Raw(string htmlString)
    {
        return new RawString(WebUtility.HtmlEncode(htmlString)); //you may not need the WebUtility.HtmlEncode here, but I did
    } 
}
```

I could then use @Html.Raw in my emails template to incorporate the editable html

```
public class Emails
{
    public static TemplateServiceConfiguration config 
                = new TemplateServiceConfiguration(); // create a new config

    public Emails()
    {   
        config.BaseTemplateType = typeof(HtmlSupportTemplateBase<>);// incorporate the Html helper class
        Engine.Razor = RazorEngineService.Create(config);// use that config to assign a new razor service
    }

    public static void SendHtmlEmail(string template,  EmailModel model)
    {           
        string emailBody 
             = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, model.Type.ToString(), typeof(EmailModel), model); 

        var smtpClient = getStaticSmtpObject(); // an external method not included here     
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(model.FromAddress);
        message.To.Add(model.EmailAddress); 
        message.Subject = model.Subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body =  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(emailBody);
        smtpClient.SendAsync(message, model); 
    }
}
```

Then I could use it by passing in the string read from the actual .cshtml template and the model holding the email data.

```
string template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ResolveConfigurationPath("~/Views/Emails/Email.cshtml"));
SendHtmlEmail(template, model);
```

ResolveConfigurationPath is another external function I found.

```
 public static string ResolveConfigurationPath(string configPath)
    {
        if (configPath.StartsWith("~/"))
        {
            // +1 to Stack Overflow:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742257/how-to-use-server-mappath-when-httpcontext-current-is-nothing

            // Support unit testing scenario where hosting environment is not initialized.
            var hostingRoot = HostingEnvironment.IsHosted
                              ? HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/")
                              : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            return Path.Combine(hostingRoot, configPath.Substring(2).Replace('/', '\\'));
        }
        return configPath;
    }
```